# Find a string based on input Characters in sql

Tags: sql-server

How to find a string based on input characters in sql?

**For example:**

Table1 column name: `desc`

```
data warehousing
sql serverl
c#.Net
asp.net
```

- My input: `@FindString='dho'` should return `'data warehousing'`
- My input: `@FindString='sv'` should return `'sql serverl'`
- My input: `@FindString='aep'` should return `'asp.net'`

How to do that?

Comment: Mind explaining why the requirement is so weird?

Comment: `aep` --> `asp.net` ?!!?!?!? You gotta explain that!

Comment: You will need to use FTS with its "Inflectional forms search feature for this [read here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) for more information on Full-text Search

Comment: @marc_s: yes, it may contain any order. String must  have all characters.

Comment: @am1r_5h: going through stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Go with this code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%d%' AND field like '%h%' AND field like '%o%'
```

I mean you should surround each character of input string with %.

Comment: It may contain any order. I mean •My input: @FindString='aep' should return 'asp.net'

Comment: Use This : SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%d%' AND field like '%h%' AND field like '%o%' .

Answer (score 0):

i think you want this :

```
declare @inputString nvarchar(max) = 'eap';

declare @where nvarchar(max) = 
    case @inputString 
        when 'dho' then 'data warehousing'
        when 'sv' then 'sql serverl'
        when 'eap' then 'asp.net'
    else ''
    end

select * from Table1
    where desc = @where
```

also your query can be like this:

```
declare @inputString nvarchar(max) = 'dho'

select * from 
   (select
        case [desc]
            when 'data warehousing' then 'dho'
            when 'sql serverl' then 'sv'
            when 'asp.net' then 'aep'
            else ''
        end 
        as [newDesc]
    from [table])t
where newDesc = @inputString
```